# How to handle sexist questions toward a faculty job candidate by other undergraduates?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, job-search, faculty-application, gender

I am an undergraduate in the U.S., and my university is currently interviewing for an open faculty position. The department arranges lunches with the job candidates and current undergraduate students, where we can ask the candidate questions and get to know them. Students fill out an evaluation of the candidate following the lunch (which is in theory taken into consideration for the hiring decision). However, the atmosphere of this meeting itself is quite informal and conversational.

Two of the candidates are currently expecting a baby. The male candidate said on their own that he was expecting a baby. One fellow undergraduate specifically asked the female candidate (in front of 20 other undergrads) if she would be able to balance a new baby and the job at the same time. However, she did not bring this up with the male candidate, who is also expecting a baby. We met with the male candidate first.

As a fellow undergraduate, how could I respectfully address this?

Comment: _how could I respectfully address this?_ — This question is unclear. What is it, _specifcally_, that you are seeking to address, and with whom?

Comment: @MadJack As confirmed by many of the responses, this behavior was clearly inappropriate. However, I am unsure whether it needs to be addressed, and if so, with whom (i.e., the department chair, the student, etc?)

Comment: Small plug, I'm trying to create a stack exchange in area51 on this topic (currently titled: race & politics dialogue, that's a work in progress since discussions of sexism are obviously relevant) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106355/race-politics-dialogue/106463#106463

Comment: The behavior was discriminatory rather than sexist. They asked the female candidate not *because she was a woman per se*, but because it's (much) more common for women to take extended maternity leave than men. Hence, asking the female candidate but not the male one was discriminatory.

Comment: **What does 'address' mean?** You want to privately give feedback to the interviewer? complain about them to someone else? suggest the dept/university should promulgate more awareness in unconscious bias leading to such questions? give guidance about how to ask about candidates intending to take leave or career breaks? incorporate that into (university?/dept?) interview training? some or all of the above? Your question is unclear, please edit it.

Answer (score 42):

There are two issues at play here depending on if you are formally part of the hiring process.

If you are formally part of the hiring processing asking questions about the family life of a job candidate, man or woman, is treading on thin ice. Even if the information is not meant to be discriminatory (e.g., as a search chair you might want to be helpful and look into spaces in the university nursery), it is just a topic you do not bring up. As a formal part of the search committee, it is reasonable to mention to the person who asked the question that family life is a topic to avoid. You may also want to mention it to the search chair so they can be prepared for any claims of discrimination.

If you are not formally part of the hiring process (e.g., potential faculty tend to like to meet students), the issue is difficult. It is perfectly reasonable, and non-sexist, for a female student to ask a female applicant about work life balance. It is a topic that a female student might have questions and concerns about for themselves going forward. Of course it could be a sexist remark to intentionally sabotage the candidate. Note that any combination of student and applicant sex could be non sexist (a male student may want to understand how their potential wife might would handle the work-life balance and a female student might want to know about how a husband would handle it). Given that, I would not raise it with the student that the question was sexist. Rather, I would point out that while the point of meeting with the candidates is to give undergraduate students exposure, that the students should be welcoming to the applicants and try and put their best foot forward. Asking about touchy subjects is not in the best interest of the department.

Comment: +1, but I have one little addition: It is easy for a student, or even a faculty member, to unwittingly find themselves in the role of an extra at an "extended interview" and not being told about it until afterwards (if at all). I have asked speakers at talks some tricky questions and only later realized that these were job talks; I am wondering whether they ended up regarding me as someone's pawn / attack dog... So, do point the problem out to the student, but do not presume without good reasons that the student was being sexist or deliberately attacking the interviewee.

Comment: "is treading on thin ice" - I'm pretty sure that in certain locations it's outright illegal, actually.

Comment: @DVK: It's hard to say here because the student isn't exactly an employee or agent of the university.

Comment: @NateEldredge - "If you are formally part of the hiring processing" is the paragraph heading. IANAL, but I don't think someone not being employee would matter in a lawsuit if it's a part of a formal process.

Comment: @NateEldredge - http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15741/does-not-being-an-employee-exempt-from-legal-responsibility-for-asking-candidate

Comment: Why is it reasonable "for a female student" to ask that, but not for a male student?

Comment: @Josef  did you read the whole answer. I go on to say a male student may want to know how their wife would handle it.

Comment: @DVK: My understanding was that asking about it isn't illegal per se; discriminating based on it is. Though when lawsuit time comes, it seems like it'd be hard to argue you didn't discriminate if you asked and then you rejected the candidate. IANAL though.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think the relevant part is "students fill out an evaluation of the candidate following the lunch (which is in theory taken into consideration for the hiring decision)."  How would you prove that the prohibited information did not color the students' evaluation?

Comment: @emory Technically you never can since humans are inherently biased. The only way to remove bias from the process is to preform double blind interviews like orchestras do. This is rarely practical or even possible depending upon the job. Someone saying something overtly biased can actually be a good thing since you can remove them and their feedback from the decision making process.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that the undergraduate falls within the typical range of undergraduates in the United States (i.e. 18 to 25) they may not have enough interviewing experience to know what is and is not an acceptable question. In the United States it is [illegal to discriminate on the basis of gender and gendered questions are to be avoided as a result](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-interviewer-ask-child-care-arrangements.html). This should be pointed out to the undergraduate in a manner that assumes good faith since they might simply not know any better. It may be helpful to provide undergraduates with examples of good - gender neutral, not overly personal or invasive, on-topic - examples of questions before the interview.

Also, it should be noted that even in professional environments, people that are new at interviewing make a lot of mistakes in terms of questions about legally protected categories. You may also want to recommend some sort of quick training session to people that are involved in searches. These sessions do not necessarily need to be that long, and even people that have been interviewing for years can always benefit from a refresher given by HR on what may and may not be legal or sensitive areas.

The best way to address it would be at the department level with undergraduates getting some sort of training before they are part of an interview panel. Calling out one person is a reactive response, while providing training to an entire group is a proactive response. In the long term proactive responses generally avoid problems all together were as they never quite go away with reactive responses.

Answer (score 15):

I would stay away from the sexism angle, since the evidence we have for sexism here seems pretty tenuous to me -- the student whose behavior offended you could plausibly argue that she forgot to ask the male candidate the same question or that the question occurred to her only after the first interview, and quite likely there were many other questions on different topics that she asked one candidate and not the other, and that's hardly proof of any malice or discriminatory beliefs.

Despite this, I think the question your fellow student asked was inadvisable regardless of the candidate's gender. Simply, having children is such a common and universal part of human experience that it would be absurd for a faculty position to carry the premise that only people without young children are qualified for the job. If I were interviewing for a position like that, I would be seriously alarmed about any hint gathered during my interviewing experience that my job will be so difficult that I cannot do it effectively and be a parent (or have other extracurricular activities I like to spend a comparable amount of time on) at the same time.

As for what you should do, if you feel comfortable discussing it with the other student in a friendly and casual way, I see nothing wrong with mentioning the concern I outlined above, but try not to be patronizing -- the goal should be to help her understand the issue rather than to reprimand her for her behavior. And as I said, do not mention sexism unless there is much more blatant evidence that that was a factor.

Another option would be to inform your department chair or other faculty member overseeing the interviewing process about your concern that some of the undergrads participating in the interview are asking questions that have the potential to sabotage the success of the recruitment. But honestly, I doubt they will be surprised to hear this rather obvious fact, and I don't think they would necessarily view it as a major concern. The candidate probably realizes that undergrads are less experienced and professional in their attitudes and that this is likely to translate to them saying some awkward or embarrassing things during the interview, and will probably just shrug it off. (In fact, believe it or not, much older senior faculty members also sometimes say foolish things in interviews. And yes, that includes me -- saying stupid things is just a part of being human, and is likely to happen occasionally however professional one makes an effort to be.)

Comment: *"Simply, having children is such a common and universal part of human experience"* -- beautiful.  Such a shame to have this lovely sentence marred by the "tenuous" paragraph.  Consider this analogy: "But Officer, I didn't see the 'No U Turn' sign."  Judges aren't looking for malice or discriminatory beliefs.  They judge *behavior, actions* and *effects.*

Comment: @aparente001 if you see clear sexism here, feel free to call it out. Let he who is without sin cast the first stone etc. Since I cannot claim to be without sin (of having asked something foolish of a job candidate, or having said something sexist ever in my life for that matter) I don't see fit to make such a judgment call here. Anyway, glad you liked a part of my answer.

Comment: Dan, the sexist behavior was on the part of the undergraduate questioner.  Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @aparente001 yes, it was clear to me that that's what you meant. I still think the evidence for sexism is tenuous (which does not mean that sexism wasn't involved, but simply that I think it's a bad idea to start throwing around accusations of it or make it the basis for further action). But it's fine if you disagree.

Comment: I think our difficulty lies in *sexism* meaning two different things.  I think you are focusing on the intent, and I'm focusing on the observable, effective discrimination that occurred.  I've had so much experience filing civil rights complaints on behalf of my son (on the basis of disability discrimination), and getting OCR's detailed analysis back of my allegations, that I've learned to set aside people's intentions, and focus on their actions.  Student asked baby care question of the woman but not of the man -- that's an observable, discriminatory *action*.  *Why* the student asked ...

Comment: ... one candidate but not the other is irrelevant in this type of analysis. // May I also point out that having children and working in academia is beautiful and universal *and accepted* when you are a man, but not so well accepted when you are a woman.

Comment: @aparente001 ok, I see where you're coming from. Well, if having children is not accepted for a woman in academia then it _should_ be accepted, which is precisely why I said questions about how to handle having children and a faculty position are inappropriate - both of a man and of a woman. Again, I personally prefer not to focus on the sexism aspect in this particular instance. But that's just my humble opinion, and I'll freely admit that other opinions are completely legitimate and may be equally or more valid.

Comment: @DanRomik I would agree with aparente001. While I do not believe the student had any intention of being sexist, the resulting action was sexist. Further, the female candidate was clearly made uncomfortable by this question and responded somewhat dismissively. The students ended up evaluating her as cold and unlikable, and I have to wonder to what extent this question contributed to that evaluation.

Comment: @KTK here's a different suggestion about what moral we can learn from this story, again without using simplistic (IMO) labels such as sexism: regrettably, it appears that it is simply a bad idea to involve undergraduates in a process as fraught with sensitive legal and psychological issues as a faculty job recruitment. One way or another, some inexperienced or immature student is going to say something foolish/racist/sexist/rude/whatever that will make the candidate uncomfortable. Again, focusing on sexism here is a mistake IMO, the issue as I see it is much broader and more general than that.

Comment: @DanRomik While I am certainly biased since I am an undergraduate myself and thoroughly enjoy being involved in the hiring process, I respectfully disagree with your statement that it is simply a bad idea to involve undergraduates. I have attended 9 such events and this is the first where such an inappropriate question has been asked. Further, it does seem that some kind of training could prevent this issue while still allowing undergrads to be involved.

Comment: @KTK thanks, it's interesting to hear the perspective of an undergrad, and in a way I am impressed with your department for being so inclusive. However, my own perspective as a department chair is different. When you are an administrator you cannot be so casual about a 1 in 9 chance (according to your stats) that something will go badly wrong during an interview, with the possibility for very serious repercussions. As I said, in this process there are already so many risk factors that are impossible to eliminate that it would be irresponsible not to eliminate at least the ones that can be. ...

Comment: ... So overall my conclusion remains the same. Finally, although it's great that you enjoyed your participation, your enjoyment (and the enjoyment of anyone else who is not the candidate) is not the goal of the process and is therefore mostly irrelevant.

Comment: I am sorry for stating my opinion, but does one single statement make one sexist?  Can a statement appear sexist, but instead just be a lapse in judgment?  Why is it we automatically jump to an extreme when we hear something that may have offended us, and seek retribution, instead of possibly talking to the person who made the statement in a non-confrontational way, in order to let the person know what he or she said was offensive.  I am NOT saying Sexism does not exist, I am just saying one should not be too fast on the trigger in reporting accusations without knowing more than one viewpoint.

Comment: @NZKshatriya I certainly do not mean to suggest that the student is sexist or had any ill intent, but I do believe this was a lapse in judgement on the student's part that resulted in a sexist _behavior_  (asking the female candidate but not the male candidate about a baby).   A lapse in judgement and sexism are not mutually exclusive, and I believe they actually often go hand-in-hand. Finally, I don't believe anyone has actually suggested seeking retribution or being confrontational towards the student.

Comment: @DanRomik Certainly my enjoyment is not the goal of the process (I just mentioned it to acknowledge that my perspective is biased). I do recognize that these odds are not great, but I also believe the risk factor could be greatly reduced/eliminated through some sort of training with the undergrads, without eliminating the benefits conveyed by including undergrads (especially considering that my university is exclusively undergraduates with an extremely heavy focus on teaching and undergrad research, so it follows for undergrads' opinions to be considered at least somewhat).

Comment: @KTK While I agree that a lack of judgement and sexism may not be dissimilar, I do have to point out that what one person may see as sexist behavior may not be as clearly sexist behavior to another. What I see as a problem as well is that some seem to want to go to administrations and file formal complaints against individuals for comments that they perceive sexist, instead of addressing the situation on an individual basis first.

Comment: @NZKshatriya I think we are interpreting the suggestions differently. I don't believe anyone has actually suggested filing formal complaints _against individuals_, rather making it known to the search committee/department chair that inappropriate questions have been asked, so they may do what they wish with that information.

Comment: @KTK I know here in the USA that asking about conditions such as pregnancy or mental illness is illegal. But If both candidates are expecting a child in the near future, would it not be within the bounds of the hiring institution to try to ascertain which candidate would be the best hire, as far as being able to balance work with either fatherhood or motherhood?  There are certainly a larger number of stay at home fathers these days, hence it could turn out that the male candidate  may choose to say home, and not the female.  Or as also happens, grandparents raise the child.

Answer (score 7):

While the faculty interviews I have been on have seen a good mix of questions from invited undergraduates to my job talks, this won't be the first time an undergraduate asks an inappropriate question during a faculty interview, and it won't be the last.

If you want to go on record with your disapproval, then bring it up with the search committee chair.

Hopefully, you got something else out of the visit with the candidates, so while you are giving your feedback to the chair about the candidates, you could also bring up your disapproval with your peer's comment. It is not your job to suggest improvements to the getting-undergraduates-involved-in-faculty-hiring process, so let the search chair worry about that.

Comment: Good answer.  I would soften *disapproval* to *concern,*  though.  I am assuming the student who asked the out-of-line question didn't know it was out-of-line, and the search committee does not include undergraduates for the purposes of sneaking in out-of-line questions.  Approaching it from the standpoint of “I saw this; it made me uncomfortable; I don't know if that's what you want from this process” seems like the right tone to take.  Especially since involving students is a thoughtful nod to their importance in the university.  I would think they would be open to that kind of feedback.

Answer (score 6):

The question has some merit, but as your question alludes it should work both ways.   Maybe not worded exactly right but it is a valid question to see if someone has enough time to put into a challenging job given that they have X going on in their life.

I am a manager in the US and we are coached away from saying certain things and I work at such a large (ultra-PC) company that we are told not even to say very basic words (like pregnant/pregnancy).  So yes the question shouldn't have been asked like that but doesn't invalidate the need for a good response.

Where I am going with this is a manager hiring someone to do something that is a challenging position with little/no experience should try to figure out what the mentality of the person is - Where do they put their work on their lifestyle scale?

> And I can go back to the biggest fail of my life was a similar
>   interview.  I was right out of college and on my 4th interview at a
>   huge finance company for a job people dream about.  Not knowing that
>   the 4th interview (with several managers) meant I was about to be
>   hired, I really didn't give the questions much thought.  The joys of
>   being a clueless (interview-wise) 22 year-old.  The hiring manager
>   knew I had two very young kids so there was a stress on the number of
>   hours I might be working and was told 70-80 could be normal.  They
>   beat this into the ground...   Well an hour into this I slipped up and
>   said something to the effect, "Do you have positions that require the
>   same skill but less work."
>
> Just so there isn't a cliffhanger... didn't get the job.  Should I
>   have?  No.  I would have hated working those hours with two little
>   ones.  And it might have been physically impossible.  It is a funny
>   story to tell about how I sabotaged myself for a job that would pay 6
>   figures by year 5.  But no regrets.

So the answer to your question of what you should do?

- Don't let people be sexist.  In this situation I would have said something to the person that said it.  Put him on the spot but in private.
- Understand that even though phrased wrong the idea behind the question is very valid for a male or female.  If I hear that a guy is on the national rugby team and does that in his spare time, I may question his ability to travel or work long hours.  It doesn't make the question sexist.  A person going into an interview should know what to say or they should be honest.
- You can certainly help a person out if a fellow interviewer asks something weird or inappropriate.  Nothing wrong with a leading question to help.

Comment: _You can certainly help a person out if a fellow interviewer asks something weird or inappropriate..._ How specifically would you suggest doing this?

Comment: @KTK something like *I am sure it is not an issue our department is great about family leave. Professor Jones just had a baby and the chair worked with her to come up with a schedule that worked for her.*

Comment: @StrongBad This seems like a very good suggestion. What alternatives might exist given that I know nothing of the department's leave policies and none of the faculty had children recently?

Comment: Pregnancy is in the same category as rugby when it comes to concerns of hiring males or females? Really?

Comment: @djechlin - no.  I am saying these are two things that could take a lot of someone's time.  It could be train collecting or whatever.  Now pregnancy is important and should be protected.  But after that men and women are on equal bearings right?  What I am getting at is - it is OK to ask a candidate if they are willing to put the hours and work into their work.  It doesn't matter the subject.

Comment: How does one "not let someone be sexist?"  Sexism is something ingrained in the person, usually by one of the parents raising them, as is Racism....

Comment: The question about the national rugby team commitment will not be considered sexist.  The question about mothering commitment will.  This is illogical, but inarguable.  I am a bad person for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

This fellow undergraduate asked a question that would in any normal job interview be illegal to ask. And nobody would ask the question, because if that candidate wasn't hired they would now be able to sue the interviewing company and win.

Since that fellow undergraduate has probably no idea about employment law, and has probably no idea how sexist their question is, you should perfectly respectfully advice him or her that if they were involved in a job interview and asked that question they would put their company's HR into an impossible situation and would get a major telling off after the candidate has left, and if they were an HR employee and asked that question they could lose their job for incompetence.

Answer (score 1):

We are not allowed to note the fact that a mother will probably require more time off due to family commitments than a father.  In some jurisdictions it is even illegal to mention the possibility.  All you have to do is remind them of this.

In fact, even MENTIONING this particular 'elephant in the room' will lay you open to criticism.  Just keep your mouth shut.  Let your collegues dig their own graves.

Comment: You realize your first sentence is one of the reasons why these policies are in place. You are judging a woman because she is a woman and not based on what the individual might be able to contribute.

Comment: Absolutely.  I am recognising that a mother may well act like a mother.  I am also recognising that it is currently forbidden to recognise this.

Comment: "act like a mother" I can't help but feel there is some inherent bias and dare I say judgment inherent in this choice of words.

Comment: Of course you can dare to say that!  There's no political correctness requirement in any discussion with me!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing for you to do.

Either

1. your university does not care about the law, ethics, professional standards, and human decency; or
2. your university is going to shred the student evaluations so they can have absolutely no impact on hiring decisions (showing the esteem the university places on student opinion).

Either way, there is nothing for you to do (except maybe transfer to a better university).

If your university esteemed student opinion; and cared about the law, ethics, professional standards, and human decency - then they would have trained the student panel and everyone on the panel would already know about this.  There would be nothing for you to do.

If your university shreds student evaluations (which I suspect they do), then they might be in technical compliance with the law.  However, there is no way for the candidate to know that.  The effect may be to discourage certain applicants from applying.

Comment: This seems like an awfully presumptive answer.  How do you know there is not a third case, like an honest mistake?  Why not infer that the department goes to the trouble of bringing students to lunch because it wants their input, and that students may not be aware of the law / ethics / professional standards involved therein?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang it is indeed possible that the department wants their input and that the students are not aware of the law.  whose fault is that? who could have done something about that but chose not to?

Comment: There is also the case that the student evaluation forms have been vetted by HR/legal and are designed to comply with the law.

Comment: @StrongBad did the students use the prohibited information to make their recommendations? did the department use the student's recommendations to make a hiring decision? In that case, the department used prohibited information to make a hiring decision.  HR/legal can not sanitize that.